# Issue with Prometheus Metrics Scraping Http_total_request

Tags: http, prometheus, metrics, promql, prometheus-node-exporter

I'm encountering an issue with Prometheus where I'm unable to retrieve HTTP-related metrics from my target.I could'nt see in metric exportor anything related to HTTP that I can query on. I am running prometheus in K8s.I've checked the configuration, logs, and queries, but haven't been able to identify the problem.

I am using prometheus version 2.49.1

```
My prome-config.yaml
kind: ConfigMap
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: prometheus
  namespace: test-tools
data:
  prometheus.yml: |
    global:
      scrape_interval:     15s
      evaluation_interval: 15s
    scrape_configs:
      - job_name: 'prometheus'
        scheme: https
        static_configs:
          - targets: ['test.com:443']
        metrics_path: /metrics  
        tls_config:
          insecure_skip_verify: true
```

When I run "up" in prometheus.I can see the targets and it scrape the metrics.But when I see in https://test.com/metrics.I dont see any descriptions related to http.Should this be add inorder for prometheus to query http?